# What does $\langle\partial_i\psi(\theta)|\psi(\theta)\rangle$ mean when implementing the Quantum Fisher information matrix?

Tags: terminology-and-notation, quantum-fisher-information

Following this [paper](https://quantum-journal.org/views/qv-2021-10-06-61/?fbclid=IwAR0ETcAR4rOJNA0VdUnSgp4gHqVo3ljqe7PB5Gy16HVVdkPjlWDtlvpuo9U), the quantum Fisher information matrix (QFIM) - $\mathcal{F}$ can be calculated as:

$\mathcal{F}_{i, j}(\theta)=4 \operatorname{Re}\left[\left\langle\partial_{i} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mid \partial_{j} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta})\right\rangle-\left\langle\partial_{i} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mid \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta})\right\rangle\left\langle\psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mid \partial_{j} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta})\right\rangle\right]$

$|\psi(\theta)\rangle$ is the current quantum state and $\theta$ is the $N$-dimensional complex vector, that means $\mathcal{F}$ is the $N\times N$ matrix.

The thing that I confused is $\partial_{k} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is a scalar so how to calculate $\langle\partial_{i} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \mid \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \rangle$ and its dagger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, $\partial_{k} \psi(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is a vector. For example, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{dx} \begin{pmatrix}x\\x^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2x\end{pmatrix}$ , i.e., the derivative is element wise when it acts on a vector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I misunderstand when thinking about $|\psi\rangle$, $|\psi\rangle$, in this case, is a $N$-dimensional vector, and its derivative $\partial\psi(\theta)$ is a $N\times N$ matrix so $\partial_k\psi(\theta)$ is also a $N$-dimensional vector.

Comment: $N\times 1$ *matrix*, a vector.

Comment: shouldn't this be a vector of derivatives, i.e. $$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\partial/\partial \theta_1\\
\partial/\partial\theta_2\\
\vdots
\end{array}\right)
$$ acting on a scalar function $\psi(\theta)$, resulting in a vector $$
\left(\begin{array}{c}\partial \psi(\theta)/\partial \theta_1\\
\partial\psi(\theta)/\partial\theta_2\\
\vdots
\end{array}\right)\quad ?
$$

Comment: @ZeroTheHero No, mind that it's $\mathcal F_{i,j} $ instead of the matrix $\mathcal F$ itself.

Comment: $\partial_i$ is only partial derivative respect to the $i$-th variable.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero If you mean the comment above of Monad, I'm not quite sure what his notation $\partial\psi(\theta)$ wants to say.

Comment: @narip that’s right: $\partial_i$ is derivative w/r to $i$’th variable but as written $d/dx$ is derivative w/r to a single variable $x$ of $i$’th component.